# Rounding to a certain decimal place and rounding to ceil or floor

Tags: java, numbers, rounding

```
private static double round (double value, int precision) {
    int scale = (int) Math.pow(10, precision);
    return (double) Math.round(value * scale) / scale;
}
```

I would like this code to not only be able to round to any given decimal place, but also to either always round up or down, this could be given as another paramter. But I am having trouble with how to implement this.

For example, I want to round 11.1436 to 11.15. Please help.

Comment: use boolean parameter boolean updown

Comment: Yes I know how to add the parameter, and I am aware of math.ceil() but I am wondering how to do math.ceil() with the added function of rounding out to a certain decimal place.

Comment: if i don't know did i understand your question correctly if it's not notify me

Comment: i updated the answer by replacing math.round to math.floor because math.floor-->round down
math.ceil -->round up

Comment: The only way to do this correctly is to change the return type to `String` or `BigDecimal` and carry out the computation in radix 10. Floating point variables don't have decimal places, they have binary places, and they aren't commensurable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

like you said you have to use math ceil to round up ,so you can pass true if you want to round up or you can pass false to round it down 
you could use

```
math.floor-->round down
math.ceil -->round up
```

instead `math.round`

```
private static double round (double value, int precision,boolean up) {
int scale = (int) Math.pow(10, precision);
if(up){
    return (double) Math.ceil(value * scale) / scale;
}else{
   return (double) Math.floor(value * scale) / scale;
}
```

output>>

```
 System.out.println(round(11.1436, 2,true)); --> 11.15 //up
 System.out.println(round(11.1436, 2,false)); --> 11.14 //down
```

Comment: to be consistent, I'd probably use Math.floor(...) instead of Math.round(...)  That way, you can truly round down when up = false.

Comment: @smertrios yes i think Math.floor is definitely round down while math.round can up or down.so i edited it

Comment: This doesn't really round to a specific number of decimal places. Floating point variables don't have decimal places. See the duplicated question.

Comment: @getlost 1. The question contains the words 'round to a certain decimal place' and 'round to any given decimal place'. 2. *Ergo* I have read the question. 3. There is no 'yelling here': flagged as offensive.

Comment: should i care about your steps